# Why is Paul Ballard working for the Dollhouse?

Tags: joss-whedon, dollhouse

In season 1 of Dollhouse, Ballard was bent on exposing the Dollhouse to the government/world. In season 2, he’s suddenly working for them and it doesn’t seem like he’s trying all that hard to help Caroline or bring down the Dollhouse. Why is he working for them now?

Comment: Have you watched all of season 2?

Comment: @HorusKol - not yet. About 5 episodes in.

Comment: Keep watching... You'll see

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is answered by watching the whole series

Comment: @HorusKol is there some rule I don't know about that says you can't ask about something mid-season? That would seem silly to me. Plus, I was asking because I felt like I might've missed something that *already* happened on the show. Sorry if my question bothered you.

Comment: its a bit like asking for a plot explanation when you've half read a book or watched half a movie. Dollhouse is just one of those shows that doesn't immediately lay it all out, but will reveal things later.

Answer (score 4):

He made a deal for the release of November (the Dollhouse sleeper agent who was his neighbour).

Comment: But since she’s free now, couldn’t he help Caroline escape or expose the Dollhouse (or both)?

Comment: @RedCaio If Paul doesn't keep his side of the deal then why should the Dollhouse? November (Millie) is  certainly not beyond their reach.

Comment: The deal also assigns him as Echo's handler allowing him to protect her as well. Looking for her is how he became so obsessed with The Dollhouse in the first place.